# Losing formating when displaying text as a label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a multiline Textbox that I acts as a description field. Large amounts of information can be added to this textbox with spacing and returns. In a Paragraph format. When i display this text later on as a `Label` I lose all my formatting and it turns into a wall of text.  Is there anything i can do to keep the original formatting?

```
var customerInfo = GetCustomerInfo(itemid);

                if (customerInfo != null)
                {
                    ItemID.Text = customerInfo.ItemID.ToString();

                    Description.Text = customerInfo.Description;

                }
```

The page Source looks like this

```
                This is a test

this is a test 

this is a test
1. test
2. test
3. test
4. tes
```

The Label/literal look like this

```
This is a test this is a test  this is a test 1. test 2. test 3. test 4. tes
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your original text? You could output your text to a DIV instead of a label control

Comment: Can you display the text in a readonly textarea? Or does it have to be converted to html?

Comment: @Guffa Can you tell me if i did something wrong. I tried this `Description.Text = customerInfo.Description.Replace("\r\n", "<br>").Replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");` and it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you display formatted text in HTML, it's not shown formatted because HTML has other methods of formatting text. All formatting characters (line breaks, tabs, et.c.) counts as spaces in HTML, so it will just be shown as a massive block of text.

To show the text formatted in HTML you have to translate the formatting into what HTML uses for formatting, for example:

```
label.Text = myText.Replace("\r\n", "<br>").Replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
```

Comment: because of your rep I trust this is probably better then what I suggested ,  isn't it the same though ?

Comment: @MUG4N - yea I don't see how manually trying to replace all encoded html is better then using built-in decoder

Comment: @ScottSelby: The `HtmlDecode` does kind of the opposite, e.g. turns `&amp;` into `&`. Not even `HtmlEncode` does the same, it just encodes some characters, e.g. turns `&` into `&amp;`, it doesn't change formatting characters into HTML equivalents.

Comment: @Guffa Can you tell me if i did something wrong. I tried this `Description.Text = customerInfo.Description.Replace("\r\n", "<br>").Replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");` and it doesnt seem to work

Comment: When i display that text in a textbox in my update page it keeps the format but not the label. I don't no if that helps

Comment: @jackncoke: You may need a Literal control instead of a Label to show the HTML code correctly. You may also need to replace other characters. If you for example use multiple spaces after each other, that is interpreted as a single space in HTML, so you would need to replace those spaces with `&nbsp;` to keep the spacing.

Comment: @Guffa That didn't seem to change anything. It isn't anything crazy just like Paragraphs and a list 1. item1 2. item2. It is not putting the `<br />`. The end user wouldn't type `<br /> ` in the textbox though.

Comment: @Guffa granted this is what i am testing with.

Comment: @jackncoke: That's odd, you should see some change at least. You would have to check what characters there actually is in the string.

Comment: @Guffa i editted the questions with more info. The view source shows it correctly which is wild.

Comment: @jackncoke: Check in the debugger what's actually in the string before you put it in the control.

Comment: I removed the `\r` from the replace method and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure with out you posting anything else, but this should help

```
 Label1.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myStringFromTxtBox);
```

Comment: I also tried yours and it didnt work i must be doing something wrong.`Description.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(customerInfo.Description);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the original text will have carriage returns -which will vary depending on the OS- for line separators but in HTML you need to translate them to `<br />` to keep the same format.

Also, Label controls are rendered as spans. You are probably better off using regular divs and setting the `runat="server"` property on them so you can programmatically assign the content.

Guffa made another good point about other characters (tab, space, etc.) All of them need to be translated to the HTML equivalent.